# Too Many Spiders

Tags: pest-control, pests, pesticide

I have a problem that could be taken care of easily if I wanted to use pesticides that kill spiders.  But I don't want to do that in my tiny space.
We live in a townhouse apartment with a small 35' x 12' yard on the back of our apt. and about 15' x 8' along the front side where our front gate is located.  I grow a few plants that I sell as individual plants and then recently have gotten into succulent, patio, zen and fairy tabletop gardens as well. I have a sensitivity to pesticides from an incident many years ago and besides, I know what they can do to other beneficial insects as well.  I would dearly appreciate any ideas to help get rid of my creepy crawly friends and their webs.  The spiders I don't mind (except for the wolf spiders ... urgggg) as much as I do their webs.  Any ideas?

Comment: How are spiders a problem?  Are you saying you see webbing on your plants?  Wolf (Hobo, Recluse) spiders would not be doing that...they are tunnel spiders and come out at night to hunt.  They belong out doors where their work is wanted!  Otherwise, you might have spider MITES.  Please send pictures!!

Comment: No not on the plants, at least not a lot.  Its on the fencing, furniture, pots and everything else around the plants.  I left my phone in the car and my husband has it, so when he gets back I'll post some pics.  We have a ton of "daddy long-legs" here, and they are prolific webbers.

Comment: Really.  Huh, we've got a great entomologist  on this site, or two or three...I am so very glad you are hesitant to use pesticides.  Lots of people become very sensitized to pesticides.  Please send pictures, morning is great as the webbing will be highlighted by dew.

Comment: I'll send pics in the morning for sure.  I'm not afraid of spiders, I've killed my share are black widows, but recognize the need for most others.  It just looks horrible when I bring people into my yard to show them plants and it looks like the Munster's live here. :>/

Answer (score 5):

I find that if you destroy the webs with a stick or something the spiders will tend to move on after a while to less disturbed locations. You probably have a lot of spiders because there's a lot of food available for them. I would consider it a good thing personally.

If you just want your yard to look good for guests, I suggest cleaning up their webs regularly and you should find fewer of them each time until the majority of them find less conspicuous locations.

Comment: I agree. Spiders should not damage your plants, but if there are so many, this could show you that there is some problems elsewhere. Check for aphids or other parasites nearby, bad soil, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I think the stick ideas will probably work.  I really don't want to hurt them, I just want them to be less conspicuous. I'll give that a try.

Comment: The other part is reducing/removing their food source(s). Things like a dripping hose bib will attract spider food.Rich damp soil can breed fruit flies among other things. (use top dressing on your potted plants) Keep food and water well sealed. If an animal can't find food, they'll find another locale.